# Program not terminates after java.util.Timer usage

Tags: java

I have simple `Timer` console application. Why this application not stops after `run` procedure was executed and still waiting for something?

```
package timer_old;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;



public final class FetchMail extends TimerTask {

  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.println("starting");
    TimerTask fetchMail = new FetchMail();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(fetchMail, 500);
    //timer.cancel();
    System.out.println("exiting");
  }

  public void run()
  {
    System.out.println("Fetching mail...");
  }


}
```

Output:

```
starting
exiting
Fetching mail...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call `timer.cancel()`   when you want the timer to terminate as soon as the run is executed.

```
public final class FetchMail extends TimerTask {
        static Timer timer=null;
      public static void main (String[] args) 
      {
        System.out.println("starting");
        TimerTask fetchMail = new FetchMail();
         timer= new Timer();
        timer.schedule(fetchMail, 3000);

        //timer.cancel();
        System.out.println("exiting");
      }

      public void run()
      {
        System.out.println("Fetching mail...");
        timer.cancel();
      }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> By default, the task execution thread does not run as a daemon thread, so it is capable of keeping an application from terminating. If a caller wants to terminate a timer's task execution thread rapidly, the caller should invoke the timer's cancel method.